# Not able to run dnu restore command from VS Code in Windows 10

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

As I change the project.json, VS Code reminds to execute restore command. When I click on restore, it gives me the below error.

```
'C:\Users\Akshar' is not recognized as an internal or external 
command, operable program or batch file. 
Press any key to continue . . .
```

dnu restore works perfectly from command line. It works on my Mac and Linux using VS Code. I'm facing problem only in Windows 10. I haven't tried in previous windows versions.

Comment: Does your user name have a space in it?  My user name is 'Jeff Ogata', and I see the same error, but it only includes up to the space: 'C:\Users\Jeff'...  This has been reported as a problem:  https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2844

Comment: Thanks Jeff. That's the problem. I had searched for the issue in VS Code's github. Never occured to check dnx's page.